# Can I use monads with clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, monads, clojurescript

I know monads are available in clojure, but has anyone verified that they work in clojurescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monads, the Functional programming method, only require a language with higher order functions and closures. You would need a ClojureScript monad library. Or you can **go ahead and write your ClojureScript in a monadic style**

EDIT: by "monadic style" I was referring to writing and composing functions that take and return monadic values and implement the three [monad laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Monad_laws). There are too many people better qualified to explain monads than I, so I will just link to [one of my personal favorite videos on monads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObR3qi4Guys).

Comment: Do you know if clojure.contrib.monads works in clojurescript?

Comment: The question is pretty clear: does Clojrue's monad library - clojure.contrib.monad - work when compiled to ClojureScript? Your answer doesn't seem to answer this at all.

Comment: it didn't at the time this question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

Monads work in clojurescript. The only thing is the way you reference macros in clojurescript [1].

What I did is copy all tools/macro.clj and all the monads.clj code into a big file which I then reference from clojurescript.

It's perhaps not the most elegant way but it works.

You can find the file in https://github.com/cotarmanach/clojurescript-monad-macros
(I copy it in my project and change the namespace to be the one of my project)

[1] See https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure

> ClojureScript's macros are written in Clojure, and are referenced via
>   the require-macros keyword in namespace declarations:
>
> (ns my.namespace   (:require-macros [my.macros :as my])) The :as
>   prefix selector is required in :require-macros. One point of note is
>   that the code generated by ClojureScript macros must target the
>   capabilities in ClojureScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great port of the [Fluokitten](https://github.com/uncomplicate/fluokitten) Library to ClojureScript by Chris Zheng: https://github.com/purnam/brahmin

Chris has a [great post reflecting on Monads](http://z.caudate.me/of-qufoids-and-the-monad-effect/) as a result of this.

The cats library for Category Theory is also good https://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/

Monads in ClojureScript is alive and well.